# Password remember on proxy login in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Google chrome is not storing password for my universities proxy login page and some other intranet sites. Pop up for remembering password is not showing when I login using username and password.

**"never saved"** box is empty in password setting in chrome.

And this is happening only in chrome, other browser like Firefox and MS edge is able to store password for that site.

Thanks

Comment: The same problem. Did you find a solution? chrome://settings/passwords  shows an empty box